# Async wrong sample in O'Reilly Book

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm reading a Book with name "Async in C# 5.0" from O'Reilly. This Book have a Wrong Async example. This example is:

```
private void u(string uri)
 {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri) < -magic(SecondHalf);
 }
 private void SecondHalf(string awaitedResult)
 {
    string page = awaitedResult;
    Console.WriteLine(page);
 }
```

Who knows the right example?

Comment: It is full of typos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the book so I just checked it. The code is meant to be pseudo-code trying to explain the code sample presented beforehand. The book explicitly says

> The interesting bit is the await keyword. When the compiler sees this,
>   it chops the method up. Exactly what it does is pretty complicated, so
>   for now I will introduce a false construct that I find useful as a way
>   to think about simple cases.

and then when describing that line of code (I added the bold formatting)

> That means we can give it the new second method, which it will call
>   when it finishes. We do this using some **magic** that I’ll tell you about
>   later.